# create new parent but use existing child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models as below:

```
class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :sites
end

class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  page_id
  belongs_to :unit
end
```

So now while creating a new Unit I always want to check if a site with the same page_id is already exist then only create a new 'Unit' but use the existing 'Site'. But if there was no `Site` with the same `page_id` then create a new Unit with a new Site.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I can think of is using Rails' `find_or_create_by` method. The documentation is [here](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by).

This way, when creating a new `Site`, you could simply do something like this:

```
u = Unit.new
u.site = Site.find_or_create_by(page_id: @page_id)
```

Where `@page_id` is the page_id in question.